# Help to approximately invert Post Newtonian expression

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, post-newtonian

Can anyone advice how to perform some sort of Taylor series approximation to compute the inverse of the following expression for $t(v)$ i.e. to obtain $v(t)$. Thanks!

$$
t(v) = t_0 - \frac{5M}{256\eta v^8} \left[ 1 + \left( \frac{743}{252} + \frac{11}{3}\eta \right)v^2 \right]
$$

Where $t_0, M$ and $\eta$ are all constants.

For those interested it's the first couple of terms from Eq. 3.8b in http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0700.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried something called a series reversion (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) however, I can't get $t(v)$ to be in the correct form to apply this.